# html5 create event handler onclick event

Tags: html, css, event-listener

I am solving Test Paper for Microsoft:Programming in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3. I didn't find the answer for this question

**Question**

You are creating a JavaScript function that displays the name of a web application. You declare the following
button element.

When a user clicks the button, a JavaScript function named About must be called. You need to create an event
handler that calls the About function when the button is clicked. Which two code segments can you use? (Each
correct answer presents a complete solution. Choose two.)

**Options**

```
 A. var button=document.getElementById("About");
    ScriptEngine.call(button,About());

 B. var button=document.getElementById("About");
    ScriptEngine.bind(button,About());

 C. var button=document.getElementById("About");
    button.addEventListener("click",About);

 D. var button=document.getElementById("About");
    button.attachEvent("onclick",About);
```

Which are correct option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option C and D are the correct answer.

See: [addEventListener and attachEvent](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm)
and
[more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Comment: I have two paper with solution in that both have different answers i.e. C and D And other have A and C so I little confuse will you give me another reference for this because that reference page not found.

Comment: Thank you Sudhir I got Answer.

Comment: @Amol addEventListener() registers a single event listener and in IE versions prior to IE 9, you have to use attachEvent